# [C++]Basic Array code that redefines y value. It's working but cannot explain why

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

I saw some codes on the web and trying to figure out how this works. I tried to leave comments on each lines but I cannot understand why y[0] changes to 5555. I'm guessing y[0] might change to numbers[0], but why? 
x value is still 1. Well.. is this because `y[0] = 1;` has no `int` data type?

#include 
    using namespace std;

```
void m(int, int []);
/*this code explains a variable m that m consists of two parts, int and int array*/

int main()
{
  int x = 1; /* x value is declared to 1*/
  int y[10]; /*Array y[10] is declared but value is not given*/
  y[0] = 1; /*Array y's first value is declared to 1 but data type is not given*/


  m(x, y); /*This invokes m with x and y*/

  cout << "x is " << x << endl; 
  cout << "y[0] is " << y[0] << endl;
  return 0;
}

void m(int number, int numbers[]) /*variable names in m are given, number and numbers.*/
{
  number = 1001; /*number has int 1001 value*/
  numbers[0] = 5555; /*This overrides y to numbers[], so y[0] =1 changes to numbers[0] = 5555.*/
}

/*This program displays 
 * x is 1
 * y[0] is 5005
 * y[0] value has changed but x has not.
 * */
```

Comment: Arrays are homogeneous in C++. If `y` is an `int[]`, it can only contain `int`s.

Comment: This was answered many times already. TL;DR: Function parameters are passed by value and changes made to them inside of functions are not visible outside. To circumvent that you pass pointers/references to functions, because changes to pointed/referenced values are not discarded. And `int numbers[]` is the same as `int *numbers` (*only when used as a function parameter*), which is a pointer.

Comment: Also `y[0] = 1;` is not a declaration, it's an assignment.

Comment: Btw, the "basic" tag is supposed to refer to the [BASIC](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) languages and is unrelated to the simplicity of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm guessing y[0] might change to numbers[0], but why? x value is still 1.

Don't guess please. Your code works as commonly expected.

`number = 1001;` doesn't influence `x` in any way.
`number` is a local copy (as passed by value).

`numbers` [decays to a pointer to the 1st element of the original array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying), thus it is changed outside the functions scope.

> Well.. is this because `y[0] = 1;` has no int data type?

No, as explained above. `y[0]` actually is of type `int`.

Comment: @user4581301 Better? Added a quantum of politeness as well ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Also you should mention to avoid the pointer decay to wrap the array in a structure. Probably his intended behavior.

Comment: @Victor Well, [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) serves that well already. No need to roll your own _structure wrapper_ for it. Should I mention it?

Answer (score 0):

`int numbers[]` is almost equivalent to `int* numbers` in this situation. You are not passing the vector as an immutable object but as a reference. So both `numbers` ( the local variable from the function ) and `y` ( the local variable from main ) will be pointing to the same memory address.

Comment: It's only a reference in a vague general sense, not in terms of the specific definition used by C++. It's the name of an array, which decays to a pointer to the 1st element.

Comment: The only difference between `int x[]` and `int* x` parameters is the spelling. They both mean "pointer to `int`".

Comment: you can't change the value of an `int x[]` but you can for an `int* x`; As in `x = 0;`

Comment: @Victor Read the link I've put in my answer.